# SQL how to connect Managers to employee

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am still a rookie and learning SQL and I am stuck with two things That I can not do

-how to Display name of employees and names of their managers but they are on same table and column

-Find the names of the employees whose manager is “Salah Mohamed”

I know I can do it with inner join but it gets strange results when I try it.

Thanks in advance.

```
Department Table:

ID   Name               MGR_ID   Branch no.
101  HR                 80021        1  
102 Technical support   80010        2  
103 Marketing           80077        3  
104 Logistics           78804        4  
105 Engineering         56651        5
```

```
Emp Table:

ID         Name        dept_id
52213   Salah Mohamed   105     
56651   Amr Saker       105     
75515   Nahed Yousef    104     
76605   Nour Waheed     102     
78804   Amr Akl         104     
80010   Ahmed Kamal     102     
80021   Ahmed Attia     101     
80045   Mona Ahmed      103     
80065   Hesham Hamdy    101    
80077   Lina Emad       103
```

Comment: I think this circular referencing is a poor idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `inner join` for entire solution and `case .. when` expression specially for the manager row as follows:

```
SELECT emp.NAME employee_name, 
       Case when emp.id <> mgr.id then mgr.NAME end as manager_name 
  FROM emp JOIN department d ON d.id = emp.dept_id
  JOIN emp mgr ON d.mgr_id = mgr.id
```

Comment: Use `where mgr.name = 'Salah Mohamed' and emp.id <> mgr.id` for second solution. For second solution you dont need `case..when` just use `mgr.name` in select clause

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it. Here you first join the employee table to department table to get the IDs of the manager. Then you join the department table to employee table again on manager id to get the names of the manager. Then you can put your manager name condition in where. Hope it helps.
Edit:

```
SELECT emp1.NAME employee_name, 
       mng.NAME  manager_name 
    FROM   emp emp1 
       JOIN department d 
         ON d.id = emp1.dept_id 
       JOIN emp mng 
         ON d.mgr_id = mng.id
     where mng.NAME='Salah Mohamed'
```

Comment: There was no output as there is no employee with manager as 'Salah Mohamed'. Where condition needs to be changed as per your requirement. if you were looking for employees with manager like 'Lina Emad' query will give you output.

Comment: Yeah I tried both Lina Emad and Amr Saker as they are both Mangers but it's still the same problem

Comment: ya you are right made a small mistake used the wrong column to join to department. Editing in the main answer too. Now it should work. : SELECT emp1.NAME employee_name, 
   mng.NAME  manager_name 
FROM   emp emp1 
   JOIN department d 
     ON d.id = emp1. dept_id 
   JOIN emp mng 
     ON d.mgr_id = mng.id
 where mng.NAME='Salah Mohamed'